# Play Viemo Video which is only embeddable on certain website

Tags: flutter, video, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am creating a Flutter app and I need to put a Vimeo video but the video is only limited to be embeddable in certain domains. I do have access to client's Vimeo developer account on Vimeo but they don't want to change this setting. Is there any way around it like using Vimeo API to play the video with certain token or something?